# PDFViewCtrl.SetDoc() blocked

Tags: pdfnet

My application has freezed one time on the instruction:

```
myReader.SetDoc();
```

With myReader instance of PDFViewCtrl.
To avoid this situation I've tried to execute this code in a new Thread with a timeout. It works but setting the document of the control in a different thread from the main one which as created the pdf control causes an uncorrect showing of the document.
I'm using .NET framework 2.0.
Any other solutions using asyncronous method seems to have the same wrong behaviour.
There is another way to put a timeout on the execution of an instruction?

Comment: does this happen with any document, or particular one?

Comment: It has happened once in a million. And trying it again with the same document it worked always. So it doesn't depend by the docuement I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If this has only ever happened once, and you cannot reproduce, then I would certainly not put SetDoc on a background thread.

Perhaps the hang had nothing to do with SetDoc call, especially since it is not reproducible.

The only thing I can think of, is if that document in question has a huge number of pages, and you are running PDFViewCtrl in a continuous page mode, but you switched to single page mode, which would load significantly faster (and which is the default mode).